# How can I replace a method into a variable inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, symfony, variables, foreach, doctrine

This is fieldsData:

```
{#1292 ▼
  +"167d580ee0": 1
  +"20fc1f0271": 2
  +"585687a0fb": 3
}
```

my Controller:

```
 foreach ($fieldsData as $uuid => $fieldId) {

  $fieldsEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($en)->findOneBy(['id' => $fieldId]);
  $name = $fieldsEntity->getName();

  $entity = new $EntityName();

  $entity->setName("test");
  $entity->setAge("test");
  $entity->setJob("test");

 }

 $this->em->persist($entity);
 $this->em->flush();
```

This works well so far. But I want to replace the method with a variable like this:

```
 foreach ($fieldsData as $uuid => $fieldId) {

   $fieldsEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($en)->findOneBy(['id' => $fieldId]);
   $name = $fieldsEntity->getName();

   $entity = new $EntityName();
   $func = 'set' . $name;
   $entity->$func("test");

 }

 $this->em->persist($entity);
 $this->em->flush();
```

But I get the error message now:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null

I do not unterstand, because when I dump `$name` I get the output:

```
name
age
job
```

Comment: Can you try using `$func = 'set' . ucfirst($name);` as you call `setName()` in your hardcoded version, but will be calling `setname()` in the second.  May make no difference, but just wanted to check.

Comment: @NigelRen  I tested it. `setname` and `setName`  works both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `$entity` on each iteration.

You said when you dump `$name` you get this output :

```
name
age
job
```

This means, the **last** iteration will result this :

```
foreach ($fieldsData as $uuid => $fieldId) {

   $fieldsEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($en)->findOneBy(['id' => $fieldId]);
   $name = $fieldsEntity->getName();

   $entity = new $EntityName();
   $func = 'set' . 'job';
   $entity->$func("test");

 }

 $this->em->persist($entity); // you didn't set name in $entity, but only job.
 $this->em->flush();
```

Move `$entity = new $EntityName();` **before** the `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Use property accessor for this job:

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

$propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
$propertyAccessor->setValue($entity, $name, 'test');
```

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#usage